# Computing terms of a sequence and proving it's convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $c_n$ be the sequence defined by 
$$c_n =1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} -2\sqrt n$$

a) Compute $c_1$, $c_2$, and $c_3$.

b)Prove that $c_n$ is a convergent sequence.

My attempt was:

a) $c_1$ = $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} -2\sqrt 1$ = $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots + 1 - 2$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} + \cdots$

and same thing for $c_2$ and $c_3$ by replacing n by 2 and 3 respectively. Concerning part b, I don't know how it's done... any help?

Comment: prove that the sequence is Cauchy

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean

Comment: $c_1 - 1 - 2 \sqrt 1 = -1.$  $c_2 = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} - 2 \sqrt 2 = 1- \frac{3 \sqrt 2}{ 2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may write
$$
c_n =\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) -\int_0^n f(x)\mathrm dx
$$ where $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},\  x> 0$. Note that since $f$ is decreasing,  we have for every $k\ge 2$,
$$
f(k-1)\ge \int_{k-1}^k f(x)\mathrm dx \ge f(k),
$$ which implies
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(k)\ge \int_1^n f(x)\mathrm dx \ge \sum_{k=2}^{n} f(k)
$$ by summing over $2\le k\le n$. This in turn implies that
$$
c_n =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(k)-\int_1^n f(x)\mathrm dx +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\ge -2
$$ and $$
c_n-c_{n+1} = \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\mathrm dx -f(n+1)\ge 0
$$ for every $n\ge 1$. As a result, bounded decreasing sequence $(c_n)$ has a finite limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n$ by monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: oh okay monotone convergence should work as well

Comment: @song Thank you, your answer was really helpful

Comment: @Lola You're welcome. I'm glad it was helpful :)

Comment: @Song what about part a? Is it how I should solve it?

Comment: @Lola Ah, since $$c_n = \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right) -2\sqrt{n},$$ it should be that $c_1 = (1) - 2\sqrt{1} =-1$, $c_2 = (1+\frac1{\sqrt{2}})-2\sqrt{2}$, etc.

Comment: @Song is $c_3$ = (1+ $1/\sqrt2$ + $1/\sqrt3$) - 2$\sqrt3$?

Comment: @Lola Yes, that is right.

Comment: okay, thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$c_n-c_{n+1}=2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/2}}=2\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-1\right)-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{1/2}}=2\sqrt{n}(n^{-1}/2+O(n^{-2}))-(n+1)^{-1/2}=-n^{-1/2}((1+1/n)^{-1/2}-1)+O(n^{-3/2})=O(n^{-3/2})$$

Comment: what is it for? and what is $O(n^{-3/2})$?

Comment: How much analysis do you know?

Comment: Not much, I'm just starting this course. We haven't done much yet

Comment: What tools/theorems are you “fluent” with? Convergence of monotonous bounded sequences? Integrals? Series? Landau notations?

Comment: Mainly integrals and series

Comment: So you can conclude, from what I wrote, that $\sum_n{c_{n+1}-c_n}$ is absolutely convergent, right?

Comment: yes, but still didnt get the O thing

Comment: Look at this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 1):

First observe that $c_n - c_{n+1} = \frac {1} {(\sqrt {n} + \sqrt {n+1})^2 \sqrt {n+1}} > 0$ for all $n \geq 1$. So the sequence $\{c_n \}$ is monotone decreasing.Also observe by recursion that $c_n = c_1 - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac {1} {(\sqrt {n} + \sqrt {n+1})^2 \sqrt {n+1}}$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Since  $\frac {1} {(\sqrt {n} + \sqrt {n+1})^2 \sqrt {n+1}} < \frac {1} {n^{\frac 3 2}}$ for all $n \geq 1$ the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {(\sqrt {n} + \sqrt {n+1})^2 \sqrt {n+1}}$ is convergent. Let the sum be $S.$  Then we have $c_n \geq  - (S+1)$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Hence the sequence $\{c_n \}$ is bounded below by $-(S+1).$ As the sequence $\{c_n \}$ is monotone decreasing and bounded below it is convergent.